# Continuity of function varying rationals and irrationals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be defined as follows:

> If $x$ is irrational then $f(x)=0$
>
> If $x$ is rational and expressed in its smallest form as $x=p/q$ then $f(x)=1/q$

I'm asked to prove that for irrational $x$, $f(x)$ is continuous and for rational $x$, $f(x)$ is not.

So let's assume $x$ is irrational, then $|f(x)-f(a)|=f(a)$ so I need to find a $\delta$ so that if $|x-a|<\delta$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ with $|f(a)|<\epsilon$. Now let's assume I choose arbitrary $\epsilon$, I need to construct $\delta$ but I have no idea how to.

Comment: Given any integer $k$, there are only finitely many rationals in any given interval with $q<k$, so it is easy to choose $\delta$ to exclude them.

Comment: @almagest I don't understand what you're saying at all. Can you be more clear please?

Comment: You have irrational $x_0$ and $\epsilon>0$. You want to find $\delta>0$ so that if $|x_0-x|<\delta$ then $|f(x)|<\epsilon$. Take a positive integer $k$ with $\frac{1}{k}<\epsilon$. Then it is sufficient to find $\delta$ so that there are no rationals with denominator $\le k$ in the interval $[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$. But there are only finitely many rationals with denominator $\le k$ in the interval $[x_0-1,x_0+1]$, so we can take $\delta$ less than the minimum distance of any of them to $x_0$.

Comment: See also popcorn function, raindrop function, the modified Dirichlet function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html

Answer (score 3):

First let me mention the problem in your approach. You start off with *"let's assume $x$ is irrational then $|f(x) - f(a)| = |f(a)|$"*. The first problem is that you have not mentioned anything about $a$ whether $a$ is rational or not.

Next when you start off with "let's assume $x$ is irrational" then perhaps you want to prove that *$f$ is continuous at $x$ if $x$ is irrational.* Thus your point under investigation is $x$. The neighboring points should then be denoted by another symbol. In the common definitions of continuity the point under investigation is normally denoted by $a$ (or $c$) and neighboring point is denoted by $x$. You seem to have mixed up something here. If point under consideration is $x$ then choose neighboring point as $y$ and then deal with inequalities of type $|f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon$.

However it is better to stick to the conventional definition and let's use $a$ as our point of investigation. Thus we start off as *"let's assume $a$ is irrational and we wish to prove that $f$ is continuous at $a$"*. Actually this is the hard part of proof so first we deal with easy part which is when $a$ is rational.

Let's assume that $a$ is rational and we prove that $f$ is not continuous at $a$. Let $a = p/q$ then $f(a) = 1/q$. Consider any $\epsilon$ with $0 < \epsilon < 1/q$. Now whatever $\delta > 0$ we choose the neighborhood $(a - \delta, a + \delta)$ will contain irrational points also. Thus for any $\delta > 0$ there is some irrational $x$ such that $|x - a| < \delta$ and then $|f(x) - f(a)| = |0 - 1/q| = 1/q > \epsilon$ and therefore $f$ is discontinuous at $a$.

Now the hard part. Let's assume that $a$ is irrational and we prove that $f$ is continuous at $a$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Now consider the inequality $$|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$$ which is same as $$|f(x)| < \epsilon$$ because $f(a) = 0$. Thus we have to find a suitable $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - a| < \delta$ then $|f(x)| < \epsilon$. We will show that such a $\delta$ exists precisely because of the fact that $a$ is irrational. Clearly we can find a positive integer $n$ such that $n > 1/\epsilon$. Consider all the rational numbers with denominator less than or equal to $n$. There will be two such rational numbers say $b$ and $c$ such that $b < a < c$ and any other rational number in $(b, c)$ is having a denominator greater than $n$ (convince yourself that it is possible to find such rational numbers, it is easy if one visualizes them on real number line instead of thinking algebraically, a proof is given at the end of the answer).

Now let's choose $\delta = \min(a - b, c - a)$ so that $$(a - \delta, a + \delta) \subseteq (b, c)$$ and therefore any rational number in the interval $(a - \delta, a + \delta)$ has a denominator greater than $n$. Now if $x$ is any number with $|x - a| < \delta$ then if $x$ is irrational then $f(x) = 0$ and the inequality $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ holds trivially. If $x$ is rational and $|x - a| < \delta$ then $x$ has denominator say $m$ such that $m > n$. Then $f(x) = 1/m < 1/n < \epsilon$ and so $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ holds. Thus for all $|x - a| < \delta$ we have $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ as required. Therefore $f$ is continuous at $a$ if $a$ is irrational.

---

**A Simple Lemma**: If $a$ is an irrational number and $n$ is a positive integer then there exist two rational numbers $b, c$ such that $a \in (b, c)$ and any rational number in interval $(b, c)$ has denominator greater than $n$ in lowest form.

**A Simple Proof**: Consider all the rational numbers of the form $p/q$ where $p, q$ have no common factor and $1 \leq q \leq n$. All these rational numbers lie as distinct points on number line (with the distance between any two points greater than $1/n^{2}$) and hence divide the whole real line into an infinite number of consecutive intervals. Since $a$ is irrational it can not be one of these division points on number line. Thus $a$ lies in one of the intervals formed say $(b, c)$. Since all the rational numbers with denominators less than or equal to $n$ are already acting as division points (i.e. end points of the intervals) any rational number in $(b, c)$ must have its denominator greater than $n$.